# Values for global Javascript variable is wrong at the momemt to get it

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iis-6

I am ready with a port from a php mvc application to asp.net mvc (using a lot of javascript and google maps). The application works quite well on my development machine (Win 7 + IIS 7). But the problems start on production server. for some reason i have a javascript file wich is not working well when i am using it from my production server.
i.e. I have my view where i load all the data from db and and after that I put this on an global variable array called global_sites_am. Each row in the array contains attributes like  latitud ,longitud and name.... After that this array is readed from the js file called maps.js.

```
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(global_sites_am[i].latitud,global_sites_am[i].longitud);
        addMarker(position,global_sites_am[i].name,i);
```

For some reason this piece of code work fine on my development machine but it doesn't when i have installed the app on production server.

I.E. On Development machine : `global_sites_am[0].latitud = 45,6789566 and  global_sites_am[i].longitud=72,69452015`

But on Production machine : `global_sites_am[0].latitud = 45 and global_sites_am[i].longitud=72`

What i am doing wrong?

Update: Here is How I load the value from the db to the javascript file:

```
global_sites_am[count]=new Object();
global_sites_am[count].name='<%=site.Name%>';
global_sites_am[count].latitud=<%=site.Latitud%>;
global_sites_am[count].longitud=<%=site.Longitud%>;
```

This is one of my properties:

```
  [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Double Latitud
    {
        get
        {
            return _Latitud;
        }
        set
        {
            OnLatitudChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Latitud");
            _Latitud = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("Latitud");
            OnLatitudChanged();
        }
    }
```

Some debug info from Chrome: http://oi49.tinypic.com/2j4q7p4.jpg. In the image you will see that the values at the moment to load in the page are correct, but at the moment to read them are wrong.

Comment: Looks like it's getting the wrong type from the database. Somewhere along the line the floats being read as an int.

Comment: I would guess that the database is using a different culture for number formating. Which could could cause a loss of precision.

Comment: Finally I think I found what is the problem. 
In the version what is working well the number are loaded as
 
    global_sites_am[count].latitud=-44.365644;
    global_sites_am[count].longitud=-73.8886;  
in the wrong version the number are loaded like 44,3635644.

How Can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was solved using the next line on the web.config:

globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US"